# Creating one for loop for 3 different variables

Tags: python

New to python here, trying to make a simple dice roller, created a func() that returns 3 variables after user input. Is there any way to make one function for the creation of the roll?
tried with range but had no luck

```
import random

def user_input():

    y = int(input("Number of yellow dice to roll? : "))
    g = int(input("Number of Green dice to roll? :"))
    b = int(input("Number of Black dice to roll? :"))
    return y, g, b

y, g, b = user_input()


for n in range(y):
    print("Yellow Dice",n+1,":",random.randint(1,6))

for n in range(g):
    print("Green Dice",n+1,":",random.randint(1,6))

for n in range(b):
    print("Black Dice",n+1,":",random.randint(1,6))
```

Comment: what is the thing that you want to achieve, can you provide an input/output example?

Comment: You could create a function which takes color and number of rolls as parameters and call it three times.

Comment: I want to create a function that receives the three user input values and generates the corresponding dice roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @MichaelButscher suggested in the comments, you can create a function that takes number and color as parameters like this:

```
def one_func(num,color):
    for i in range(num):
        print(f"Dado {color} {i+1} : {random.randint(1,6)}")
```

Then, call this function in your `texto()` function three times.

```
def texto():
    a = int(input("Dados Amarillos que deseas tirar: "))
    v = int(input("Dados Verdes que deseas tirar: "))
    n = int(input("Dados Negros que deseas tirar: "))

    one_func(a,"Amarillo")    
    one_func(v,"Verde")
    one_func(n,"Negro")
```

**Note**: `function` names referred to [post-edit question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58194192/1). I also saw the error that wrong `variable` naming caused you from that post-edit question.

Comment: thanks, yea edited the post because maybe language wise it wasn't clear what i was trying to achieve. but your post made it clear thx!

Answer (score 0):

Depend on what you want to archive and `a,v,n` values (must be the same range). If `a,v,n` are not the same range, you should keep your code like that.

This is just an example for you.

```py
>>>for a,b,c in range(3), range(1,4), range(2,5):
...    print(a,b,c)

0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
```